# Different product page layouts on different stores with magento multi-store

Tags: magento

So here is my quandry..

I have three stores all with seperate themes.

I want the actual layout of the product page to vary between stores. So for instance I would like to include full description on one and only short descitopn on the other and would like to add a tag line field in another. Basically all three will need complete sepearate layouts.

I think the product page layout is drawn from `app/design/front/base` (as a standard layout).

Can I include the relevant files (and directories) from base into `app/design/frontend/default/theme` to allow me to achieve the above?

I think the file I need to edit/copy is the `view.phtml`? Can you confirm this also?

Answer (score 0):

you have to copy view.phtml to related theme of your store and modify/add/delete the code in view.phtml

to remove anything just comment the code in view.phtml file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also copy catalog.xml to related theme of store. If want to remove description or add other details of products.